# Oracle SQL: Exists, Distinct (Multiple Columns Combo), Order BY

Tags: subquery, sql-order-by, distinct, exists, where-in

Oracle SQL: (Select all columns based on unique value with combination of column: activity + column: r_system that has the latest column: end_date)

**Sample Data**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJPCq.png

**Attempt**:

SELECT T1.* FROM happy T1
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT DISTINCT T2.activity,T2.r_system, MAX(T2.END_DATE)

FROM happy  T2

WHERE T1.activity=T2.activity,T1.r_system=T2.r_system, T1.END_DATE=T2.END_DATE

GROUP BY T2.activity, T2.r_system

ORDER BY MAX(T2.END_DATE) DESC,T2.r_system, T2.activity
)

Answer (score 0):

Credit to: [How to grab the last value in a column per user for the last date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71861283/how-to-grab-the-last-value-in-a-column-per-user-for-the-last-date)

**Result:**

select
*
from
happy
where
(
activity,
r_system,
END_DATE
)
in
(
select
activity,
r_system,
max(END_DATE)
from
happy
group by
activity,
r_system
)
order by
activity,
r_system,
END_DATE